# Airflow Scheduling: how to run initial setup task only once?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

If my DAG is this

**[setup] -> [processing-task] -> [end]**.

How can I schedule this DAG to run periodically, while running **[setup]** task only once (on first scheduled run) and skipping it for all later runs?

Comment: What does `setup` do? Is it necessary to include it as a task in the DAG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [post in medium](https://medium.com/@plieningerweb/use-apache-airflow-to-run-task-exactly-once-6fb70ca5e7ec) which describes how to implement a "run once" operator. I have successfully used this several times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it without need to create a new class. I found this simpler than the accepted answer and it worked well for my use case.

Might be useful for others!

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id='your_dag_id',
    default_args={
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'email': ['you@email.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    description='Dag with initial setup task that only runs on start_date',
    start_date=datetime(2000, 1, 1),
    # Runs daily at 1 am
    schedule_interval='0 1 * * *',
    # catchup must be true if start_date is before datetime.now()
    catchup=True,
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:

    def branch_fn(**kwargs):
        # Have to make sure start_date will equal data_interval_start on first run
        # This dag is daily but since the schedule_interval is set to 1 am data_interval_start would be 
        # 2000-01-01 01:00:00 when it needs to be
        # 2000-01-01 00:00:00
        date = kwargs['data_interval_start'].replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
        if date == dag.start_date:
            return 'initial_task'
        else:
            return 'skip_initial_task'

    branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch_task', 
        python_callable=branch_fn,
        provide_context=True
    )

    initial_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id="initial_task"
    )
    
    skip_initial_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id="skip_initial_task"
    )

    next_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id="next_task",
        # This is important otherwise next_task would be skipped
        trigger_rule="one_success"
    )

    branch_task >> [initial_task, skip_initial_task] >> next_task
```